# Чтение arraylist с External storage

Tags: java, android

Есть файл sample.txt во внешней памяти, у которого такая структура 
[Строка1, Строка2]. Как преобразовать этот файл в ArrayList.

Comment: прочитать, разделить и положить в ArrayList. Хотите конкретики - выкладывайте содержимое файла и ваш код.

Answer (score 2):

Просто строки через запятую? Или каждая строка в отдельной строке? Не совсем понимаю в чем у вас проблема

1) Читайте файл в строку, как-то так:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
 byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
 String str = new String(encoded, encoding); // encoding - нужная кодировка
```

2) Удаляйте '[' и ']'

```
 str = str.trim();
 str = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
```

3) Делите на массив строк

```
 String[] arr = str.split(",");
```

4) Превращаете в ArrayList

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(arr);
```

Comment: А что делать с квадратными скобками в начале и конце

Comment: обезать по одному символу у строки с каждого края? str1 = str.substring(1, str.length - 1) ? Можно для надежности убрать пробелы перед этим str = str.trim();

Comment: У меня кодировка UTF-8, на "UTF-8" он жалуется.
И подскажите пожалуйста как path описать.